# Spring boot file read error cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring boot file read error  cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:

```
    // Gets the XML file under src/main/resources folder
    Resource sourceFile = new ClassPathResource("jrxml/report.jrxml");

    String jrxmlFilePath = sourceFile.getFile().getPath();
```

Requirement 
1.Spring boot project jar file
2.File read 
3.File upload

Comment: I guess that file is not included in jar file. You can check whether it exists by extracting your jar file using 7zip or winzip. Then checking your package process.

Answer (score 3):

When you build your application, the files in the resources folder are copied to the target directory (where the compiled class files are placed, where the CLASSPATH points to) and this target directory is then put into a jar file.

Let's look at your problem line by line:

```
    // Gets the XML file under src/main/resources folder
```

This comment is wrong. It does not get the file from the src/... folder, because this folder contains source files but your program is running in either a jar file or in a folder that contains compiled .class files, and it has no knowledge of a src/... folder.

```
    Resource sourceFile = new ClassPathResource("jrxml/report.jrxml");
```

The variable name is misleading. It's not necessarily a file; it could be, and typically is, a jar entry.

```
    String jrxmlFilePath = sourceFile.getFile().getPath();
```

This is where you are getting the exception. `sourceFile.getFile()` is documented thus, [as you can see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/AbstractFileResolvingResource.html#getFile()):

> This implementation returns a File reference for the underlying class path resource, provided that it refers to a file in the file system.

And, as your error message says, it's not in the file system.

What you need to do is get the resource as an InputStream instead of as a file:

```
    Resource jrxmlResource = new ClassPathResource("jrxml/report.jrxml");
    InputStream jrxmlStream = jrxmlResource.getInputStream();
```

You can then open the stream and read from it, or pass it to whatever needs to read it. Just don't use it as if it were a file, because it's not.

Answer (score 1):

try `getResouceAsStream()` to read file under resource folder.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStreamReader in = null;
try {
    in = new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("jrxml/report.jrxml"));
    ...
} catch (...) {
} finally {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If file is in resources folder then use,

```
Resource sourceFile = new ClassPathResource("report.jrxml");
```

Comment: We cannot use that way in spring boot jar file.giving above error.